# How to find corresponding version of MyBatis Generator for MyBatis 3.4.2?

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator

I want **MyBatis Generator** generate for me source code for working with MyBatis version **3.4.2** . How to choose suitable version of **MyBatis Generator**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the latest one.

According to [the documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/generator/index.html) for the current (1.3.7) version:

> MyBatis Generator (MBG) is a code generator for MyBatis MyBatis and
>   iBATIS. It will generate code for all versions of MyBatis, and
>   versions of iBATIS after version 2.2.0